# Fatal error: Class 'JAccessRule' not found in /home/www/xxx/libraries/legacy/access/rule.php on line 22

Tags: php, joomla2.5

[this page](http://newporttours.dk/) has encountered the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'JAccessRule' not found in
>   /home/www/newporttours.dk/libraries/legacy/access/rule.php on line 22

I tried replacing this

```
class JRule extends JAccessRule
{
```

With this

```
class JAccessRule
{
```

On line 22. Then the frontend just returned "JAccessRule cannot be resolved"

I have no idea about the history of this site, if someone tried to upgrade it or what. I just had it handed down.

Please help :-)

Comment: you need to include the JAccessRule class above the class definition. `include "path/to/JAccessRule.php";`

Comment: Pasted the error into the question, fixed format and grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a PHP error which happens when you try to use a class. When you say that

```
class JRule extends JAccessRule
{
```

then you essentially say that `JRule` inherits `JAccessRule`, but since your `JAccessRule` class is not loaded when this file is loaded, you get the error. You need to require_once the location of the file which contains `JAccessRule` before you define this `class`.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't touched anything in the code. According to the guy who owns the site, the error seemed to appear "out of nowhere". I don't really believe that - it seems they have tried to upgrade stuff without checking compatibility. This problem transcends my abilities somewhat, that is why I ask for help.

If you could help me with a code line which I could copy/paste into the rule.php file, I would be grateful :-)

Comment: @AztridSalamander, I would happily tell you what to do, but I am a total noob in Joomla. I have searched for your class and have seen this: http://www.phoca.cz/joomla/api/class-JAccessRule.html. It's in the Joomla\Platform\Access package. Can you, by any chance add that package using an admin panel to the loader?

Comment: Hi @Lajos, I shall give it a try :-) You gave me another idea: I could just make a clean install using the templates Quick Start option, then grab the file from there! Thank you :-)

Comment: @AztridSalamander, glad to help. Please, let me know the result of your try.

Comment: Hi @Lajos, so I downloaded the template again, then in the quick start folder I located another file calle "rule.php" in the folder /libraries/joomla/access/ . I replaced the defective rule.php in the live sites legacy folder with this one, as it contained a definition of class JAccessRule. It was kind of a long shot but it seems to be working ...

Comment: @AztridSalamander, that's great news! If my answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it

Comment: how do I do that? I tried to give it a "useful" arrow, but that didn't work. EDIT: Found the check mark :-)